# TinyMCE images wrong path saved in database. Showing only in editor itself

Tags: php, url, tinymce

This is saved in the database. And when viewed in editor in admin it displays images, however on frontend not, probably because of the ../../uploads which is correct only from the admin.

```
<p>it amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris aliquet elementum mi, ac adipiscing metus suscipit in. Quisque venenatis ante non nulla faucibus viverra. In ultrices nisl sit amet quam commodo ut feugiat magna aliquet. Aenean sit amet odio magna. Maecenas pretium ante a urna dictum vel dignissim erat porta. Aenean rhoncus elementum nisi, nec euismod est tempus commodo. Phasellus sapien nisl, lacinia vel ultrices consectetur, rhoncus vitae dolor. Sed lobortis diam at felis volutpat aliquet. Pellentesque massa neque, tempus ut dignissim at, ultricies a ante. Nam a imperdiet dolor. Ut placerat nisi nec mauris ornare eu ultrices urna tincidunt.</p>
<p>
<img width="710" height="376" alt="" src="../../uploads/pages/image/dog.jpg">
</p>
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, solved by myself ;). I need to add this in TinyMCE init:

```
  document_base_url : "http://domain.name",    
  relative_urls : false, 
  remove_script_host : false,
```